# Как в cmake добавить sfml

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

Как на linux в cmake добавить sfml, у меня установлена sfml.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(SFML LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(SFML main.cpp)
```

Comment: [FindSFML](https://github.com/SFML/SFML-Game-Development-Book/blob/master/CMake/FindSFML.cmake), потом `find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)`

Comment: Нужно его сбилдить, затем найти через `find_package()`. Find'ы устарели, сейчас все используют Config'и. Это более правильно.

Comment: Огромный минус документации CMake - там нет примеров, так что я тебя понимаю. Год назад я тоже ничерта не понимал. Читай чужие `CMakeLists.txt` файлы